# React Native Maps MapView.fitToCoordinates crashes app when testing (Expo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

When using MapView.fitToCoordinates, the application closes with no error message:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';


export default function App() {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView 
        ref={mapRef}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        }}
        onLayout={()=>{
          mapRef.current.fitToCoordinates({latitude: 34.5, longitude: 82.5})
        }}
      >
      </MapView>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo you should import from `expo` instead of `react-native-maps`. Expo does include react-native-maps already.

Example: `import { MapView, Marker } from 'expo';`

There is a more detailed answer on react-native-maps with expo available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57598895/13990578

Comment: That is no longer supported with expo SDK 38.0, instead you should import from 'react-native-maps', which has the crash that I specified